# POCOs and utility methods

Tags: c#, poco

Lets assume that I have a POCO class that contains `foos` and `bars`:

```
public class Poco {
  public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }

  private List<Foo> foos;
  private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

In my example I need to be able to add and remove `foos` and `bars`:

```
public class Poco {
  public IList<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
  public IList<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }

  private List<Foo> foos;
  private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

But lets say that I also need the (arbitrary) constraint that there must be one `foo` per `bar` and also one `bar` per `foo`.

```
public class NotAPocoAnyMore {
  public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }

  private List<Foo> foos;
  private List<Bar> bars;

  public void Add(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
  public void Remove(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
}
```

My question is this: Am I getting to worked up about trying to keep a POCO simple and not give it any utility methods? The first example POCO is nice because it is immutable, and POCOs have other advantages. However, I can't see a way to keep the class a POCO and still have ways to access and modify the contents in a controlled way (at least not a way that doesn't seem over-kill).

Some thought that I have had:

**Nested modifying class**

```
public class Poco {
  public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }
  public PocoModifier Modifier { get { ... } }

  private List<Foo> foos;
  private List<Bar> bars;

  public class PocoModifier {
    private readonly Poco toModify;
    public void Add(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
    public void Remove(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
    ...
  }
}
```

Public nested class? No thanks! Also it really is just the same as the non-POCO class just with a little more nesting.

**Using access modifiers**

```
public class Poco {
  public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }
  public PocoModifier Modifier { get { ... } }

  internal List<Foo> foos;
  internal List<Bar> bars;
}

public class PocoModifier {
  private readonly Poco toModify;
  public void Add(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
  public void Remove(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
  ...
}
```

Slightly better, but requires a whole unit of deployment for each POCO.

Comment: Personally I don't mind having utility methods on your POCOs (even if they aren't really POCOs anymore). Another option is to create a separate extension method library or static PocoModifier that's external to your POCOs (so you aren't nesting classes), but the feasibility of that depends on if you are exposing your POCO to a client.

Comment: To me it seems like you pull business logic into your entities. Write the business logic in a separate layer.

Comment: Feels like you have set of arbitrary restrictions you personally decided to force on your code... Maybe if you think about why you are doing it you can decide it on your own... Side note: your first object is not really immutable - you are exposing lists to start with (require cast, but who will be stopped by that) and not showing any other methods...

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like your data would be better modeled by something that naturally pairs a `Foo` with a `Bar`.

```
public class Poco {
  public IList<Tuple<Foo, Bar>> FooBars { get { return fooBars; } }

  private List<Tuple<Foo, Bar>> fooBars;
}
```

Unless for some strange reason the `Foo`s and `Bar`s are completely separate except for the requirement that their count is the same. Then I like your third example...

```
public class NotAPocoAnyMore {
  public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get { return foos; } }
  public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }

  private List<Foo> foos;
  private List<Bar> bars;

  public void Add(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
  public void Remove(Foo f, Bar b) {...}
}
```

`PocoModifier` adds unnecessary complexity, in my opinion. And nested classes should generally not be public (so if you have the class at all, make it separate like in your last example).

If you need a POCO to work with as well (e.g. to expose that publicly to people using your code as a library, while keeping other logic internal), you might create a plain POCO and then map it to `NotAPocoAnyMore` with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (or similar).

```
public class Poco {
  public IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
  public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

POCOs only represents a unit of data/information. Once you start enforcing rules either as a constraint or as a way for better organizing your data, you start defining behaviour of your data. Suddenly, you are not dealing with POCOs anymore and It becomes a full blown Data Structure.

How you implement this is up to you. If you want to work with POCOs, you can segregate your data and the behaviour by using Helpers/Extensions or whatever you fancy or you can build your own Data Structure by combining the data and it's behaviour in a single entity.

There is nothing wrong with either of them and while some people prefer working with POCOs, I usually prefer working with Data Structures that encapsulates data and it's behaviour in a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

I go with repositories to handle persisting POCOs (using EF). Here is an example of a generic repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    ...
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{   
    // dbset or list or whatever you're persisting to

    public void Add(T entity) {
       // add to dbSet
    }     
    public void Remove(T entity) {
       // remove from dbSet
    }
}
```

And it's usage

```
var repo = new Repository<User>();
repo.Add(new User());
```

You now aren't muddying up your POCOs and have an object specifically designed to persist your POCO. I'm not a fan of generic repositories - was good for a quick example. You can make repositories specific for each entity with more specific retrieval methods.